# Finding running low

Tags: c++

I have a vector of structs containing the following type of variables:

```
Date      Time   Low
11/1/17   929    74.25
11/1/17   930    73
11/1/17   931    75
11/1/17   932    70
```

etc.

I now want to add another struct to my vector called "LowRun", where LowRun is the smallest low at every point in the iteration, like so:

```
Date      Time   Low    LowRun
11/1/17   929    74.25   74.25
11/1/17   930    73      73
11/1/17   931    75      73
11/1/17   932    70      70
```

This is what I've tried so far, but this is not giving the right output:

```
edited:


int CalcLow_SoFar(std::vector<PriceInfo>& p)


    double running_low = p[0].Low;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < p.size(); ++i)
    {


        if (p[i].Time > 929
            && p[i].Time < 1601
            && p[i].Date == p[i - 1].Date)


        { 


            if (p[i].Low < running_low)
                {
                    running_low = p[i].Low;
                    p[i].LowRun = running_low;

                } 


        }

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Can you help me get unstuck, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried initializing your variable, `double running_low = p[0].Low;`?  Your compiler probably has a warning for that, if you turn on your compiler's warnings.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: Thanks Eljay. Tried that but didn't make a difference. I'm assuming that the correct way is to initialize it outside the for loop?

Comment: You might want to try [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). You've got multiple weird logic problems.

Comment: Hi Fei, I've been talking to the duck for a couple of days. But I'm obviously not as talented as you...

Comment: What is the last if statement for?

Comment: Explain to me or your rubber duck what this condition does: `if (p[i].Low < p[i-1].Low)`.

Comment: I think I see now, it has to be if (p[I].Low < running_low) ?

Comment: CraigR, last if statement in my OP is weird, as Fei said. I've cut it out, it shouldn't be there

Comment: Have you tried normal debugging? Have you confirmed that you actually enter the first `if` statement? Is your `.Date` comparison correct for whatever type it is?

Comment: Hi ssell, yes, I added a cout in the second if statement and it spits it out at runtime. The code compiles but the issue is that I'm getting a memory address  (1.04353e-305) in my output file for the LowRun variable

Comment: That's not a memory address. That's scientific notation for a very small (close to 0) value caused by you reading uninitialized variables. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several weird logic problems in your code, so I'm just going to list them here.

- This if statement makes no sense: `if (p[i].Low < p[i-1].Low)`. You assign `running_low` to the current value whenever the current value is less than the previous value. However, it's perfectly possible for the value to decrease while not being lower than the running low. For example, if you have the sequence `1, 3, 2`, the `LowRun` value at the index 2 gets assigned to 2 because 2 is less than 3, even though the running low should be 1.
- The if statement after the one I was talking about (`if (p[i+1].Low < running_low)`) would have been good if you didn't add 1 to `i` for some reason. Instead of going from 1 to `p.size()` - 1, you're now going from 2 to `p.size()`, so you access one element past the end of the vector which is undefined behavior.
- You only assigned the `LowRun` values when the `running_low` value changes. This means that if a value didn't change the running low, it's `LowRun` value is uninitialized which is where the garbage values come from.
- You didn't initialize `running_low` to the first element.
- I don't know the details of what you're doing, but the condition checking the time and date looks suspicious, so I've removed it for now. It basically ignores an entry if it's the first one on that day. If that's what you want to do, instead of initializing `running_low` to the value of the first element, initialize it to something like `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` so it's guaranteed to get updated on the first valid entry and change your loop to start from 0.

This doesn't affect the functionality, but unlike `main()`, other functions you define don't have to return an int or even anything at all. Use `void` if you don't need the function to return anything.

Lastly, you should get in the habit of using good formatting including proper indents so you don't confuse yourself.

The fixed code:

```
void CalcLow_SoFar(std::vector<PriceInfo>& p)
{
    double running_low = p[0].Low;
    p[0].LowRun = p[0].Low;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < p.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (p[i].Low < running_low)
        {
            running_low = p[i].Low;
        }
        p[i].LowRun = running_low;
    }
}
```

Version with the date and time checks:

```
void CalcLow_SoFar(std::vector<PriceInfo>& p)
{
    double running_low = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (p[i].Time > 929
            && p[i].Time < 1601
            && i != 0
            && p[i].Date == p[i - 1].Date
            && p[i].Low < running_low)
        {
            running_low = p[i].Low;
        }
        p[i].LowRun = running_low;
    }
}
```

Note that for this version, the `Low` values for the first few elements will be a very large value since a valid entry hasn't been encountered and `running_low` still holds the value we initialized it to.

Here's the version which only includes the values from the same day in the running low and also ignores any values with a time not in [930, 1600]:

```
void CalcLow_SoFar(std::vector<PriceInfo>& p)
{
    double running_low;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0 || p[i].Date != p[i - 1].Date)
        {
            running_low = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
        }
        if (p[i].Time >= 930
            && p[i].Time <= 1600
            && p[i].Low < running_low)
        {
            running_low = p[i].Low;
        }
        p[i].LowRun = running_low;
    }
}
```

Similar to the second version in this answer, the `LowRun` values might be `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` if a value in that day within the time limits hasn't been encountered yet.

Comment: Thank you Fei, noted on all your explanations which I appreciate greatly. The output is closer to the result I need but not quite: re the suspicious time and date check, what I'm trying to do with that is restrict the finding of the session low to each day. So at any point in the iteration, only find the running low if it is within the bounds of 930 to 1600 time wise and within the bounds of that date. The input file covers a year worth of data, so approx. 250 days, with each day running from midnight to 1800. Does that sort of make sense?

Comment: @EksanaStasis So you only want the running lows to include the values in the same day? Do do that, we can simply reset the `running_low` whenever we encounter a new day. I'm still not sure what you mean by the part about the time. Do you want to ignore entries that aren't in a certain time period? Also, there are `>=` and `<=` operators.

Comment: Yes to answer your first question above. Re time,  yes, want to ignore everything outside the 930 to 1600 window

Comment: Thanks so much Fei, while the 2nd to last solution didn't work, the last one (with 930 and 1600 in it) did! I'm going to study your code to make sure I understand it.